# How to properly setup form-validator-render

Tags: php, forms, validation, zend-framework

I'm trying to set a form-validator-render-controller this way:

Form:

```
<?php
namespace Application\Form;
use Zend\Form\Form;

class AjouterCompteForm extends Form
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'role',
            'attributes' => array(
                'label' => 'Rôle',
                'class' => 'form-control',
            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'ajouter',
            'attributes' => array(
                'type' => 'submit',
                'label' => 'Ajouter',
                'class' => 'btn btn-primary',
            ),
        ));        
    }
}

?>
```

Validator:

```
<?php
namespace Application\Validator;

use Zend\Db\ResultSet\Row;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Zend\InputFilter\Factory as InputFactory;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterAwareInterface;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterInterface;

class AjouterCompteValidator extends Row implements InputFilterAwareInterface
{    
    protected $inputFilter;

    public function setInputFilter(InputFilterInterface $inputFilter){
        throw new \Exception("Non utilisée");
    }

    public function getInputFilter()
    {
        if (!$this->inputFilter) {
            $inputFilter = new InputFilter();
            $factory = new InputFactory();

            $inputFilter->add(
                'name' => 'role',
                'required' => true                
            );

            $this->inputFilter = $inputFilter;
        }

        return $this->inputFilter;
    }
}
?>
```

render:

```
<?php

$form = $this->form;
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('compte', array('action' => 'ajouter')));
echo $this->form()->openTag($form);

?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?php 
        echo $this->formSelect($form->get('role')); 
        echo $this->formElementErrors($form->get('role'));
    ?>
</div>

<?php
    echo $this->formButton($form->get('submit'));
    echo $this->formElementErrors($form->get('submit'));
?>
```

Doing that I get the following error message:

> Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormSelect::render requires that the element is
>   of type Zend\Form\Element\Select

How to fix that, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All elements setup in your form constructor should have a type:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'role',
        'type' => 'select', // <- add this line
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Rôle',
        ),
        'attributes' => array(
            'class' => 'form-control',
        ),
    ));

    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'ajouter',
        'type' => 'submit', // <- add this line
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Ajouter',
        ),
        'attributes' => array(
            'type' => 'submit', // <- this line is unnecessary
            'class' => 'btn btn-primary',
        ),
    ));        
}
```

Comment: Doing that I get this error message: `File:Fieldset.php:223 Message:No element by the name of [submit] found in form`.

Comment: Ah yes, I missed that. That's because your submit element is named `ajouter`, not `submit`. When you pass a form element to the form helpers you load them by name, not by type.

Comment: You're right. I'm now getting `Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormButton::render expects either button content as the second argument, or that the element provided has a label value; neither found`

Comment: These are all separate issues to the one in your initial question. Label is not an attribute, it should be specified as an option. I've updated my answer with the correct syntax for this.